# How do i set counter for separate 3 buttons that will increase by 5, 10, 20 if clicked

Tags: java, android

How do i set counter for separate 3 buttons that will increase by 5, 10, 20 if clicked.

Suppose,

Button A will count 5 if clicked
Button B will count 10 if clicked
Button C will count 20 if click

and, It will Increase on Every Click.....

Comment: Have you wrote any code ?

Comment: Yes..  

int count = 0;
 plusOnePoint.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count ++;
                String current_user_Id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                storeUserDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(current_user_Id);
                storeUserDatabaseReference.child("user_point").setValue(+count);
            }
        });

Answer (score 0):

First initialise counters like below,

```
int mainCounter = 0; 

int buttonOneCounter = 5; 
int buttonTwoCounter = 10; 
int buttonThreeCounter = 20;
```

When button 1 click

```
mainCounter+=buttonOneCounter;
```

When button 2 click

```
mainCounter+=buttonTwoCounter;
```

When button 3 click

```
mainCounter+=buttonThreeCounter;
```

Comment: Wow! Problem Solved !!

Comment: Thanks a lot Lucifer bro

Answer (score 0):

**activity_main.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Counter = 0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonA_onClick"
        android:text="Button A" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonB_onClick"
        android:text="Button B" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="buttonC_onClick"
        android:text="Button C" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView textView_counter;
    private int counter = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView_counter = findViewById(R.id.textView_counter);
    }

    public void buttonA_onClick(View view) {
        counter += 5;
        textView_counter.setText("Counter = " + counter);
    }

    public void buttonB_onClick(View view) {
        counter += 10;
        textView_counter.setText("Counter = " + counter);
    }

    public void buttonC_onClick(View view) {
        counter += 20;
        textView_counter.setText("Counter = " + counter);
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot <3